# Visual Studio debug mode throws breakpoints for opencv HoughLines()

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and OpenCv 3.0. I'm using the `HoughLines` function for line extraction. If I run the code in **Release** mode, the VS does not throw any errors/exceptions.

If I run the code in Debug mode, than for the mentioned function (`HoughLines`) triggers a breakpoint in VS. If I let it continue, than the following exception is thrown:

> Unhandled exception at 0x77AAE753 (ntdll.dll) in trackingLines.exe:
>    0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77AE4270).

The exception is thrown at line 
`_Container_proxy *_Parent_proxy = _Parent->_Myproxy;` in **xutility** file in `VS/VC/include`

How should I setup the Debug exception list in order to be able to debug my code without this exception?

What causes this exception?

My code:

> ```
> #include <iostream>
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <ctime>
>
> #include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
> #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
> #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
> #include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
>
> #include "opencv\cv.h"
> #include "opencv\highgui.h"
>
> #include <string.h>
> #include <iostream>
> #include <fstream>
>
> using namespace cv;
> using namespace std;
>
> int main( int _argc, char** _argv )
> {
> Mat src, src_bev;
> Mat src_gray, src_d;  
> IplImage * imageIn = cvLoadImage("img1.jpg"); 
> src = cvarrToMat(imageIn,true);   
> int  lowThreshold = 32, ratio = 1;
> Canny( src, src_gray, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*((double)ratio/10+2), 3 );
> vector<Vec2f> lines;  
> HoughLines(src_gray, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 100, 0, 0 );    
> return 0;
> }
> ```

Please don't mind that first I'm reading in an `Iplimage` and than I convert it to `Mat`. There are no problems with reading the image or displaying. The only problem is whit the `HoughLines` function call.

Comment: "Please don't mind that first I'm reading in an Iplimage" - yet this is most likely the problem. both the exception above *and* the fact, that you do not use imread() (WHY ?) hint to a linking problem with the std c++ libs. are you mixing debug/release libs ? multithreaded-dll c-runtime (also debug version, if ness.) ? again, check your linker settings *very carefully* , also please revert using to imread()

Comment: I'm going to receive an `Iplimage` from an other software tool. I understand that it is outdated to use this data type and if I could, I would use only `Mat`. This is only the testing phase of my algorithm, and I would like to have the debug mode.
I'm using the same Lib. from opencv for debugging and release, namely (all): `opencv_world300.lib;opencv_ts300.lib;kernel32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)`

Comment: ok. i mistook it for some related problem, sorry. and i meant more the opencv libs, only those ending in d should be used in debug mode. but the 1st thing you should do is check, if your input image was valid at all. `if ( src.empty() ) // bahhh`

Comment: r u sure about the libs and bins you use?

Comment: what do u mean? I only added the `opencv` libs, the others are standard in a new project (I guess).

Comment: Make sure you add the debug opencv libs to your debug configuration not the release versions.

Comment: Also make sure you use the ones for Visual Studio 2012. These should be in the vc11 folder.

Comment: Thanks @berak, the `d` ended libs had to be included.